# Does Wassenaar Arrangement on the transfers of conventional arms and dual-use goods and technologies apply to security training?

Tags: professional-education, exploit-development

Does the [Wassenaar Arrangement](http://www.wassenaar.org/) on the transfers of conventional arms and dual-use goods and technologies apply to security training?
Does it apply to security training on exploitation techniques?
Is it applicable to institutions or individuals?

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be an infosec question. More legal.

Comment: Legal questions are sometimes on topic here. Voting to leave open

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting legal advice, which not only may vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction but also from case to case, and so should be obtained from a qualified legal practitioner in the appropriate jurisdiction rather than from the Internet where the well-meaning and logical opinions you receive on the matter may leave you more ill-advised than if you hadn't asked at all.

Comment: What do you mean by off-topic ? my question is relaed to information security trainings.